# Как конвертировать .py в .exe

Tags: python, windows, macos, exe, конвертация

Я создал игру на питоне используя библиотеки `pygame`, `wxPython` и хочу конвертировать главный файл в `.exe` так чтобы эта игра работала на таком устройстве на котором нету питона или использованных библиотек.
Есть ли какая-то прога или библиотека для исполнения этой задачи?
Нужно чтобы работало в Windows, и как конвертировать .exe в исполняемый файл для OSX ?

Comment: pyinstaller, py2exe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте cx_Freeze.

```
python -m pip install cx_Freeze --upgrade
```

В корне вашей игры создаете файл "setup.py" примерно такого содержания:

```
from cx_Freeze import Executable, setup

# Список всех файлов и папок вашего проекта, за исключением исполняемого, 
# находящихся в корневой папке
include_files = ['game', 'test']  # file or directory

options = {
'build_exe': {
    'include_msvcr': True,
    'build_exe': 'name_exe',
    'include_files': include_files,
    }
}

# Задаем исполняемый файл и свою иконку.
executables = [
    Executable("game.py", icon='game.ico'),
]

setup(
    name="game",
    version="1.0",
    description="Game",
    executables=executables,
    options=options,
)
```

Ну а дальше из корневой папки выполняем

```
python setup.py build
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

```
pyinstaller your_program.py
```

Comment: я пробовал, не работает, всё конвертируется но не работает

Comment: вот проект, если можете посмотрите

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1-1gv4zRb-ZTK8NXEKPu7GSYxsownvJ-A?usp=sharing

Comment: @E_d_u_a_r_d Ну если не работает, то наверно ошибка в коде, а не при сборке.